# NodeJS Asyn/Await for build configuration with nodecloud-config-client

Tags: node.js

My NodeJS application is using spring cloud server for configurations and I am loading this at the application startup. I am using the below function to load config but I can see the promise status is pending and seems to be the call is still async. How can I make it as a sync call to wait until the configurations are loaded. Thanks in advance!

```
async function fetchConfig(){
    await client.getConfig().then(conf => {
        console.log(conf);
    }).catch(console.error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

async/await is a way to replace promise based callback, but you use them at same time, you can change it to:

```js
async function fetchConfig(){
  try {
    const conf = await client.getConfig();
    console.log(conf);
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error(ex);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. I already tried this approach, but the result is a promise with 'pending' promise status.